# How to find the argument of $\cos 2 - i\sin 2$

Tags: complex-numbers

> How would you find the argument of the following number.
>   $$\cos{2}-i\sin{2}$$

I'm aware that complex numbers in the form $r(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})$ have an argument of $\theta$, but what do you do with the $-$ sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of method, you will demonstrate some knowledge of Euler's identity and/or trigonometric identities.

### Method I: Arctangent of slope

The argument is the arctangent of the ratio of the imaginary component to the real component, *accounting for quadrant*.  If you forget to account for quadrant, this gives arguments in the interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, "half" of which are wrong.  (Recall that arctangent is not a single-valued inverse.  This is obvious when one remembers that tangent is periodic.)

Since $\cos 2 < 0$ and $-\sin 2 < 0$, this is in quadrant III.
\begin{align*}
\arctan \frac{-\sin 2}{\cos 2} &= \arctan(-\tan 2))  \\
    &= - \arctan \tan 2  &&\text{$\arctan$ is an odd function}\\
    &= - \arctan \tan (2 - \pi)  &&\text{$\tan$ has period $\pi$}\\
    &= -(2 - \pi +\pi k), k \in \mathbb{Z}  &&-\pi/2 < 2 - \pi < \pi/2  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
Choosing $k=1$, this lands in quadrant III, giving the argument $-2$.  If we had just mechanically evaluated, say with a calculator, \begin{align*}
\arctan \frac{-\sin 2}{\cos 2} &= \arctan(2.18504\dots)  \\
    &= 1.14159\dots{} + \pi k, k \in \mathbb{Z}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
The subset of these in quadrant III have $k$ odd.  Picking $k = -1$, we get $-2$.

Of all the $k$ that give a result in the correct quadrant, which do you pick?  You pick the one that conforms to your conventions for the range of value of an argument, if you have such a convention.  If you do not, pick the one that makes your subsequent steps easier (or don't pick and leave the result as an equivalence class $\mod 2 \pi$).

### Method II: Conjugation

If your only problem is the wrong sign of imaginary component, use conjugation.  \begin{align*}
    \arg(\cos 2 - \mathrm{i} \sin 2) &= \arg(\overline{\cos 2 + \mathrm{i} \sin 2})  \\
    &= \arg(\overline{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} 2}})  \\
    &= -\arg(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} 2})  \\
    &= -2  \text{.}
\end{align*}

### Method III: Even-odd identities

Sine is odd.  Cosine is even.  This is expressed in the [even-odd identities](https://brilliant.org/wiki/trigonometric-even-odd-functions/).  So $\cos(-2) = \cos(2)$ and $\sin(-2) = -\sin(2)$.  Consequently, \begin{align*}
    \cos 2 - \mathrm{i} \sin 2 &= \cos -2 + \mathrm{i} \sin -2  \\
    &= \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(-2)}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
having argument $-2$.

[Brahadeesh's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2422783/123905) and [MrYouMath's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2422787/123905) answers use this method, without identifying what was done.  [Michael Rozenberg's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2422784/123905) answer combines this with the [periodicity (by $2\pi$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Shifts_and_periodicity) identity, again without identifying what was done.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has really cleared things up for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can write this complex number as $\cos(-2) + i \sin(-2)$. Now you can see that the argument is $-2$.

Answer (score 0):

$z=r(\sin\theta+i\sin\theta)$, where $r\geq0$ and $\theta=\arg{z}\in[0,2\pi)$.

$$\cos2-i\sin2=\cos(2\pi-2)+i\sin(2\pi-2).$$

Thus, $\arg(\cos2-i\sin2)=2\pi-2$.

Comment: Thank you. Am I right in thinking then that there is a general rule that r(cosA-isinA)=r(cos(2π-A)+isin(2π-A))?

Comment: @Ewan Miller It depends on definition. Sometimes $\arg{z}\in[0,2\pi)$ and sometimes $\arg{z}\in[-\pi,\pi)$. You need to ask your teacher.  I like the first versa.

Comment: In the case where $\arg{z}\in[-\pi,\pi)$, would it be r(cosA-isinA)=r(cos(-A)+isini(-A))?

Comment: Also, I haven't got a teacher as I have just left school and am teaching this to myself in my gap year

Comment: @Ewan Miller It's not so easy. If $A\in(-\pi,\pi)$ then you are right:$r(\cos(-A)+i\sin(-A))$ , but for $A=-\pi$  we get $r(\cos{A}+i\sin{A})$. All this depend on the level of your teacher. Maybe he don't see here problems.